# How to forward iPhone SMS with original received/sent date stamps attached on iOS 6.1

Tags: sms

I receive text messages on my iPhone.
When I forward them, the original sender's contact info and date time stamp do not forward with it.

Is there a way to include this information when forwarding to my email?

Comment: 'forwarding to my email' — you're forwarding SMS to your email? How exactly are you doing this?

Answer (score 1):

sms will always have the time stamp from the time and sender of the message.  not the message you're quoting.

if you want some evidence of timing etc, take a screen cap of original message and send that as an mms to the next person.  clunky, but might help